# Is the sentence „Птицы не любят такого леса“ grammatically correct, and why?

Tags: отрицание

> Несмотря на тишину и покой, птицы не любят такого леса и предпочитают
> держаться в молодых зарослях.

[link (Mamin-Sibiryak)](https://www.euroki.org/diktanti/ya-lyublyu-severnyy-les-za-torzhestvennuyu-tishinu-kotoraya-tsarit-v-nem-osobenno-horosho-v-samom-gustom-elnike-tema-kontrolnyy-diktant-za-god)

Despite being a Russian speaker myself, I have some trouble with the accusative/genitive.
I assume Mamin-Sibiryak is a classical Russian writer, so he couldn't be wrong.

**So if someone asks me, «Вы любите эту книгу?», can I reply, «Нет, я не люблю этой книги!»
or «Я не люблю этой лошади», «Я не люблю жены», «Я не люблю стола», «Я не люблю шкафа», etc.?**

This may be a strange question for an adult, but are my sentences correct?

«Я не люблю фатального исхода...»

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So if someone asks me: «Вы любите эту книгу?», can I reply: «Нет, я не люблю этой книги!» or «Я не люблю этой лошади», «Я не люблю жены», «Я не люблю стола», «Я не люблю шкафа», etc.?

The genitive is preferred in negative sentences when the object is indefinite. This is one of the few instances in Russian where the concept of definiteness is conveyed on the syntactic level.

In all your examples, the objects are definite, so the accusative would be preferred here.

Mamin-Sibiryak's excerpt means "birds don't like such a forest". Here, "forest" is indefinite: birds don't dislike this particular forest, they dislike any forest like this. Had it been *птицы не любят этот лес*, the accusative would be better justified.

Similarly, Vysotsky's lyric, weirdly put as it is, doesn't exactly mean "I don't like the fatal outcome". It's more of "I don't like fatal outcomes", and in prose it should have been worded *я не люблю фатальных исходов*. In this case, the author is exercising his poetic license.

Comment: Great answer and great English!

Answer (score -2):

> *В лесной глуши*
>
> *Я люблю северный лес за торжественную тишину каторая царит в нем. Особено хорошо в густом ельнике где нибудь на дне глубокого лога.*
>
> *Между древесными стволами обросшими в течении десятилетий седым мхом и узорчатыми лишаями кое где проглядывают клочъя неба. Свесившиися
> лапчатые ветви деревьев кажутся какими то гиганскими руками.
> Фантастический характер предают картине леса громадные папаротники,
> которые тапорщатся перистыми листьями. Мягхкий желтоватый мох
> скрадывает малейший звук и вы, точно, идёте по ковру. Прибавте к этому
> слабое освещение падающие косыми полосами сверху.*
>
> *Как то немного жутко зделается когда прямо с солнципека войдёшь в густую тень вековых елей.*
>
> *Не смотря на тишину и покой птицы нелюбят такого леса и предпочитают держатся в молодых зараслях. В настоящую лесную глуш забераются только
> белка да пёстрый дятел. Изредко ухает филин, вдалеке надрывается
> кукушка.*

***Птицы не любят такого** леса = птицы не любят **этого** леса = птицы не любят **это** - такого леса.* И если "отмотать" назад, то можно прочитать какого "такого" леса не любят птицы: густого, елового, мшистого, слабо освещенного и тд.

***Птицы не любят густого, елового, мшистого, слабоосвещенного леса.*** - **Birds don't pleased with the dense, spruce, mossy, lightless kind of forest.** (я не уверен в правильности предлога with в английском языке, так что тут сами)

Я не люблю жены - не совсем верно, однако, можно сказать: "Я не люблю жён, дворцов, ракушек".

Хотя, говоря о себе в эээ, с отстраненной позиции, можно сказать:
*"Он думает, я не люблю жены"(жена **моя**, я не люблю **своей** жены); "я думаю, что не люблю своей жены"; "не люблю его жены; я не люблю жены"(тут о себе с отстраненной позиции, я - это не я, я смотрю на себя со стороны, говорю о себе с позиции третьего лица); "я не люблю жены - сказал он", - вроде того; "ты не любишь жены"*(своей); "ты говоришь, я не люблю жены?", ну и тд.

Также можно сказать:

*Он не любит жены* (подразумевается **своей/его/евойной** жены), *а он не любит жену* (не известно чью, может свою, определенность будет зависеть от контекста), *он не любит дворца* (этого дворца, о котором говорим, или говорилось, или собеседник должен знать о каком), *он не любит дворец*(какой-то не известный дворец, может в Питере, а может в Москве).

*"The genitive is preferred in negative sentences when the object is indefinite. This is one of the few instances in Russian where the concept of definiteness is conveyed on the syntactic level."*

Так тут всё как раз наоборот: **родительный падеж указывает на определенность и конкретность, которая точно есть в контексте, или человек знает о чём речь, или есть местоимение, по которому можно определить, к кому относится "это" дополнение, и применяется чаще всего в связке с местоимением. Определенность зависит от контекста или местоимения.**

Также если речь идет не о "неопределенных" моментах, а о признаках:

***Я не люблю зелёного стола*** - **я не люблю зелёного**, а стола - это дополнение согласованное с зеленого. Если бы было "я не люблю зеленый стол", было бы "я не люблю стол" - согласование указывает на конкретизацию того, что именно не любит человек - цвет стола или стол. И признак и цвет конкретные, так что весьма определенные. Я не люблю зелёного стола - я не люблю зелень у стола.

***"Я не люблю фатального исхода,"*** - **я не люблю фатальное, фатальность** или **я не люблю (такой) фатальности**, а не "исходы". Фатальность определять не надо, так как она по умолчанию не является неопределенной или определенной, поэтому местоимение ставить не обязательно.

**Также и птицы не любят такого леса** - **Птицы не любят такого** + леса

Ну и в конце скажу, что "я люблю/не люблю" - это абсолютно не "I like/don't like", а либо I love, либо I pleased/don't pleased. I like ([like - "having the same characteristics or qualities" (as another)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/like#:%7E:text=%22having%20the%20same%20characteristics%20or%20qualities%22%20(as%20another)%2C)) - это "я отношусь нормально, мне норм", либо "мне подходит, мне под стать, я уподобляюсь".